# Is CodedUI test supported on Windows Server 2012

Tags: xcode-ui-testing

I have created a CodedUI test for an application that only runs on Windows Server 2012.  The test can detect the object controls via DrawHighlight, however it does not recognize any mouse click or keyboard actions.

Has anyone successfully run a CodedUI test on Windows Server 2012 platform?  Is CodedUI supported on Windows Server platform?

Comment: It runs fine on my 2012 r2 systems. Did you mean 2012 or 2012 R2?